# how to loop on an argument in Java

Tags: java, loops, arguments

I have method which has 2 arguments ,first argument is String type which is constant, but the second argument i want it variable ?
the method is :

```
  public  void  fun (String name,int id) {
         int [] pathIdsArray ;
         pathIdsArray = GetPathIDsFromDB (name,id);
       for (int i = 0; i < pathIdsArray.length; i++) {
    String strBlock = GetFun (name , id , pathIdsArray[i]);
    addFun(strBlock);
  } 
    }
```

if i write pass values directly, i'll be like this:

```
obj.fun("Abc", 1);
 obj.fun("Abc", 2);
 obj.fun("Abc", 3);
 obj.fun("Abc", 4);
 obj.fun("Abc", 5);
 obj.fun("Abc", 6);etc
```

but i want it in loop the second argument,but not the first one, i tried but it isn't working:

```
 int[] id=null;
int j=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < id.length; i++) {
         j = id[i];

    }
 fun("003", j);
```

Comment: Please explain better.

Comment: Please format your code. It's horrible to read now.

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < id.length; i++)` is a perfect `NPE`. 2 lines before you set `id` to `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code with throw **[NullPointerException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html)**. You have not initialized your `id[]` array before using it.

```
int[] id=null; // You need to create an array object to make this code work
int j=0;
// id.length with throw NPE
for (int i = 0; i < id.length; i++) {
  j = id[i]; // id[] is null
```

Replace `id=null` with `id = new int[SIZE];` and populate the array with desired values.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but

```
int[] id=null;
```

then how can this work

```
for (int i = 0; i < id.length; i++)
```

The array `id` will need to be initialized before being used.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int[] ids = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
for (int i : ids) {
    objectItem1.LoadFromDB("003", i);
}
```

Comment: I have assumed that u will have ids from 1-6